# Javascript: How to call an API over HTTPS and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, ssl, tornado

Previously my website was on http protocol, so doing this in my javascript worked:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'http://x.x.x:5000/sthng',
                    type: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(uname + ":" + pass)
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result)
                    }
                 });
```

But as http is not secure, I shifted to HTTPS. How should I make the ajax call when I'm trying to access HTTPS website?

Btw I'm using Tornado web server which is in front of Flask API. My Tornado server code is like this:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler, RequestHandler, Application
from flask-file import app
import tornado.httpserver

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("This message comes from Tornado ^_^")

class getToken(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("hello")

tr = WSGIContainer(app)

application = Application([
(r'/', getToken),
(r"/tornado", MainHandler),
(r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=tr)),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options={
        "certfile": "C:/x/key.pem",
        "keyfile": "C:/x/server.key",
  })
  http_server.listen(5000)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This is the error I'm getting in Tornado every time Javascript (using url: 'https://x.x.x:5000/sthng' in AJAX) calls the API:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback (<socket.socket fd=344, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 5000)>, <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x000000000499FD90>) Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 883, in
    start handler_func(fd_obj, events)  
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in
    null_wrapper  return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 274, in
    accept_handler callback(connection, address)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 239, in
    _handle_connection do_handshake_on_connect=False) 
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 510, in
    ssl_wrap_socket context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 487, in
    ssl_options_to_context context.load_cert_chain(ssl_options['certfile'],
    ssl_options.get('keyfile', None)) ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2515)
```

Also: doing curl gives me this:
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to x.x.x:5000

Really lost here! Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to set up the secure server properly, with a valid certificate

Comment: @JaromandaX The certificate is valid and verified. I didn't create it personally.

Comment: maybe [this](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the datatype to "jsonp", that's helped me for cross-origin requests.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://x.x.x:5000/sthng/"
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
        }
 });
```

no need of type: get as ajax call defaults to 'get'

Comment: Still same issue .. I think the issue is with authentication and not with what is being returned

Comment: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

is certificate expired?

Comment: No. It will expire in another couple of years. Are you sure its an issue with the certificate? I had a feeling it has gotten something to do with my ajax call.

Comment: If you have access to this https://x.x.x:5000, then you can try using ngrok to create one pubilc url for it and make ajax call.

I am sure your ajax call has no issues, something wrong with ssl settings.